# typescript creating a method that takes any derived subclass instance as parameter

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Based on the typescript docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html, here's an example of simple inheritance:

```
abstract class Animal {
    name: string;
    constructor(theName: string) { this.name = theName; }
    move(distanceInMeters: number = 0) {
        console.log(`${this.name} moved ${distanceInMeters}m.`);
    }
    hello() {
        console.log(`hello`)
    }
}

class Snake extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(distanceInMeters = 5) {
        console.log("Slithering...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}

class Horse extends Animal {
    constructor(name: string) { super(name); }
    move(distanceInMeters = 45) {
        console.log("Galloping...");
        super.move(distanceInMeters);
    }
}
```

Let's say `Animal` is abstract, so it shouldn't be instantiated. How can one create a function that agnostically takes an instance of any of Animal's subclasses?

Something like

```
function printHello(subclass: //any subclass of Animal) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: `function printHello(subclass: Animal)` does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can one create a function that agnostically takes an instance of any of `Animal`'s subclasses?

It can just accept `Animal`, since subclasses can be used as arguments for superclass parameters:

```
function printHello(subclass: Animal) {
    // whatever
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggOwJYFthkEBvAWACgFqFth8BTALgUil2wHMBuSmpAPbY2AV3gCoACggALBgDl6zVtA6cAlKQSzcYAHR1GCALza5ixtwQBfPjXwCAbg0kATXRGDZYDAJLYAWQYIBigwFmwRfBBQkwQABk1yKn4aWCEwAWQGPWQBTkkAAwASEh19QwZrBAdnVwRS90gvH38gkLDrfD1C9V4U6lsBhDlkPMkku1TBYSycvILC0bzeqZtKIcoUNAwAZToAawYEBgAPEOxXDBwCIlI19OFoMQgJSUqWNjUk1hEAB1C7yUfXWw1qLianm8fkCwVCGFMAFZJsN+I9MtlcvlJAAiXbIXCyUJqPSknF9Nb8MD-UJ6cFuDwtGHteEU4ZDTYUbboBAACQkYGOZwuVyweEIxGSaIyz3EUg+KnYXB+1IB8uBViG-HpkKZbThYTiABZkfdUWkMnMsQUcQBxIh5P4ksls6bUVW0nWM6H6jpgV00DmUSgAMxE3gguCECD+SogvIYYwEkmpIG54TFt2QKOls0xCxTIjTqHQBg1G2DFFjHHjifG2AYAHcEPtgEdcbt0GBDgxyX0gA)

Since `Animal` is abstract, you know the instance you're passed will be a subtype.